# Class 'phpQuery' not found

Tags: php, yii2, php7, phpquery

Пришлось перейти с PHP 5.6 на PHP 7, и после перехода вот такая ошибка:

> Class 'phpQuery' not found

Код:

```
$body = $res->getBody();
$document = \phpQuery::newDocumentHTML($body);
$price = $document->find($price_tag);
$active = $document->find($tag_active);
```

Это парсер, хотелось бы исправить эту ошибку, иначе придётся откатывать назад на 5.6, а это переписывать один функционал.

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно у Вас пакет с phpQuerry был установлен под старую версию которая стояла на тот момент.
Попробуйте установить расширение под новую версию

```
atp-get install php7.0-xml
```